# Code in blobs detection java in the migrated android does not work

Tags: android, opencv, blob, detect

I have the code below running on java in eclipse and it works very well. I migrated to the android studio , but always appears a black image on the camera display. I can not the same result. Can someone help me?

Input image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-HZe0eHDlhEOWh1OEt2SVB4UkU/view?usp=sharing

Output image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-HZe0eHDlhEMEFDYnZwaVRkWjA/view?usp=sharing

```
    /* Code in Java eclipse*/

    System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );

    Mat matsrc = Highgui.imread("E:\\skin.jpg",Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Mat mathsv = matsrc.clone();
    Mat matwhite = matsrc.clone();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(matsrc, mathsv,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    Core.inRange(mathsv, new Scalar(0, 100, 100), new Scalar(10, 255, 255), matwhite);

    Imgproc.erode(matwhite, matwhite, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(5, 5)) );
    Imgproc.dilate( matwhite, matwhite, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(5, 5)) ); 

    Imgproc.dilate( matwhite, matwhite, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(5, 5)) ); 
    Imgproc.erode(matwhite, matwhite, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(5, 5)) );

    Mat matFim = matwhite.clone();
    Core.bitwise_and(matsrc, matsrc, matFim, matwhite);


    Highgui.imwrite("e:\\skinOut.jpg", matFim);


    /* Code in Android studio*/

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat matsrc = inputFrame.rgba();
    Mat mathsv = matsrc.clone();
    Mat matwhite = matsrc.clone();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(matsrc, mathsv,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    //red color
    Core.inRange(mathsv, new Scalar(0, 100, 100), new Scalar(10, 255, 255), matwhite);

    Imgproc.erode(matwhite, matwhite, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(5, 5)) );
    Imgproc.dilate( matwhite, matwhite, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(5, 5)) );

    Imgproc.dilate( matwhite, matwhite, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(5, 5)) );
    Imgproc.erode(matwhite, matwhite, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(5, 5)) );

    Mat matFim = matwhite.clone();



    Core.bitwise_and(matsrc, matsrc, matFim, matwhite);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(matFim, matFim, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(matFim, matFim, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2RGBA);

    return matFim;

    }
```

Comment: in android you are taking rgba(4 channel)  into matsrc then coverting BGR2HSV(3 channel) .I think this may be problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your android code there may be problem with this line `Imgproc.cvtColor(matsrc, mathsv,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);` since you are taking input as camera frame in **RGBA** format, but using `Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV` flag for conversion to `HSV` which would swap the internal channel orientation. So you must use `Imgproc.cvtColor(matsrc, mathsv,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);` in case of Android.

This should be done because in your eclipse project, You are reading image directly using Opencv `imread()` method, which implicitly converts your `RGB` to `BGR`(Opencv native format), But in case of Android you are not using `imread` so the image is read in `RGB` format.

There are 2 solutions to overcome this issue:

- Use `Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV` flag while converting to HSV format
- Swap the color range values as `Core.inRange(mathsv, new Scalar(100, 100, 0), new Scalar(255, 255, 10), matwhite);` in android code.

Comment: Thanks ZdaR, worked for exchanging COLOR_RGB2HSV .

I'm working on a master's project developing an application to detect spots on human skin. You can help me in other things I need going forward ? How can we contact us ?